# How to make bootstrap modal to vertical align: top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal with Boostrap 3 patch for for bootstrap-modal. The Modal is good after this patch. But I need to align it vertically top not on the middle.

The Boostrap 3 patch has below css which is making it to be appear in  vertically middle but i need vertically top aling, please suggest.

```
body.modal-open, 
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top, 
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.modal {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  z-index: 1050;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.modal.container {
  max-width: none;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
}
```

Comment: Try to add `.modal{ top : 0 }`

Comment: its not working

Comment: After adding what @Ramesh suggested, did you make sure you are removing `.modal { bottom: auto; }`.

Comment: if i am removing bottom: auto then its coming to vertical align: bottom

Comment: @acd37  No need to remove `bottom:auto`. It will behave as you wanted since there is no pointed value for bottom. in future you can override the value

Comment: Can I get a fiddle of your code?

Comment: For a modal demo click on  Add Deal  http://webapplications.co.in/nextstep/deal.html

Comment: I need frame Modal should appear from top.

Answer (score 0):

By default, modals are vertically-aligned with the top in Bootstrap 3.  It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish with your patch. If you're wanting to do something custom, start by looking at the source code. If you don't have it already, you can download it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/). This is the path to the file you need: bootstrap-3.3.7 > less > modals.less.

Your code is not following the same structure as the Bootstrap 3 source code. The comments at the top of the modals.less file put the purposes of the main modal classes very succinctly:

> // .modal-open      - body class for killing the scroll
>
> // .modal           - container to scroll within
>
> // .modal-dialog    - positioning shell for the actual modal
>
> // .modal-content   - actual modal w/ bg and corners and shit

Edit: Having looked over the live site you linked to in the comments, you are missing some wrapping div tags in your HTML that implement the .modal-dialogue and .modal-content styling rules. It appears your patch is trying to compensate for those Bootstrap classes you've omitted. Though it looks okay in most instances, it is causing your modals to display incorrectly and makes their behavior and positioning much harder to adjust and predict.

Here is a simple example modal showing how the HTML needs to be structured that I've copied from the [Bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#live-demo):

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you remove your modal patches and follow the pattern in the code above, you should get the desired results.

Hope this helps. Best of luck.

Comment: I want frame modal which should appear from top webapplications.co.in/nextstep/deal.html